# Parametric representation of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z \le 2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, parametric

just wondering how to parametrize this. Question is:

Let $C$ denote the conical region $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z \le 2$. Find a parametric representation $\mathbf{x}(u,v)$ for $S$, the surface of $C$. (Hint: you'll need to split it into two parts.)

[Other parts to the question (that I can probably do after the parameterisation):
Use simple geometry to write down the outwards pointing unit vector at each point on $S$.
Find the surface area of the cone.]

I thought that maybe the parametrization could be $$\mathbf{x}(u,v)=(v\cos{u},v\sin{u},v)$$ with $0\le u\le2\pi$ and $0\le v\le 2$ but this would give me the volume of the cone if I integrated over it... Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: Your parametrization is ok; the problem is about the integral you use. You should select the surface integral, and now the volume integral, if you want to compute the surface of the cone. Could you please add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, the surface integral is

$$S=\int_{D(u,v)}\|x_u \times x_v\|dudv, $$

where $D(u,v)=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^{2} |   0\leq u\leq 2\pi, 0\leq v\leq 2\}$ and

$$x_u=(-v\sin u, v\cos u, 0), $$

$$x_v=(\cos u,\sin u, 1). $$

A quick computation gives $\|x_u\times x_v\|=\sqrt{2v^2}=\sqrt{2}v$.
We arrive at

$$S=\int_{D(u,v)}\|x_u \times x_v\|dudv=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{2}vdudv= 
2\pi\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{2}2^2=4\sqrt{2}\pi.$$